paragraph.clear() caused bookmark.getPosition() to shifted
I have a google docs with 2 bookmarks in it. Bookmarks are in different paragraphs.
Docs structure is something like this:
             | ...(other content)...
[bookmark-0] | Text-0
             | ...(other content)...
[bookmark-1] | Text-1
             | ...(other content)...

I'm running this script
function removeTextContent() {
  const docsId = '...';
  const docs = DocumentApp.openById(docsId);
  const doc = docs.getTabs()[0];
  const bookmarks = doc.asDocumentTab().getBookmarks();

  for (const [index, bookmark] of bookmarks.entries()) {
    Logger.log(bookmark.getId()); // output correct values
    const position = bookmark.getPosition(); // get shifted in 2nd iteration
    const element = position.getElement();
    const paragraph = element.asParagraph();
    paragraph.clear();
    position.insertText(String(index));
  }
}

Expected result:
             | ...(other content)...
[bookmark-0] | 0
             | ...(other content)...
[bookmark-1] | 1
             | ...(other content)...

Actual result:
             | ...(other content)...
[bookmark-0] | 1
             | ...(other content)...
[bookmark-1] | Text-1
             | ...(other content)...

Further debugging shows that in 2nd iteration position get shifted hence position.insertText() in the 2nd iteration put value at the wrong position.
This code also gives the same behavior
paragraph.getChild(0).removeFromParent(); // instead of paragraph.clear()

My goal is to replace the content of bookmarks with "something else" while keeping the bookmarks .getId() intact.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Further examination shows the problem isn't related to the order of bookmarks but because the code previously works from top to bottom.
Changing this
for (const [index, bookmark] of bookmarks.entries()) {
  // code
}

to this
for (const [index, bookmark] of bookmarks.reverse().entries()) {
  // code
}

solves the problem.
It's worth to note that when working with Position it's a good idea to always work from bottom to top, for good reasons.
==============
As for the order problem, I've created an example in github to workaround this issue.
The idea is to define the order yourself.
const config = [
  {
    imageName: 'Figure 1',
    bookmarkId: 'id.wglkb02zor96'
  },
  {
    imageName: 'Figure 2',
    bookmarkId: 'id.ifl1btgwoni'
  },
  {
    imageName: 'Figure 3',
    bookmarkId: 'kix.jithfpq0bbwm'
  }
];

Then use that order to work the bookmarks.
const docsId = '...';
const docs = DocumentApp.openById(docsId);
const doc = docs.getTabs()[0];
const bookmarks = doc.asDocumentTab().getBookmarks();

const bookmarkOrder = config.map(item => item.bookmarkId);
bookmarks.sort((a, b) => { // order bookmarks using config
  const indexA = bookmarkOrder.indexOf(a.getId());
  const indexB = bookmarkOrder.indexOf(b.getId());
  return indexA - indexB;
});

Alas, it's a shame that an important feature like bookmark is not well-behaved.

This is a known issue reported on Google's Issue Tracker, not intended to be fixed yet due to the age of the requests, lack of activity, and the total number of people reporting the issue.
As per the individual assigned on the last ticket, Google Docs script editor bug. Element.clear/deleteText/setText not working in conjuction with bookmark.getposition:

I'm marking this issue as obsolete because it hasn't received many votes and it's been a while since it was reported. If you still believe that this issue is important, please comment below with additional details or open a new issue. Thank you for your feedback!

Their recommendation is to open a new ticket to let them know that the issue is still going on.
TL;DR
The following are the bug reports and feature requests submitted on Google's Issue Tracker:

getBookmarks() returns unordered, request ability to sort returned Bookmarks.
Google Docs script editor bug. Element.clear/deleteText/setText not working in conjuction with bookmark.getposition

Their current status is Won't fix (Obsolete) due to the reasons stated above, whereas they were created on Feb 3, 2015 05:29AM and Apr 27, 2018 07:14AM, respectively.

Thank you for pointing out this issue. I wasn't aware of this issue because previously I was working with only 2 bookmarks and this issue didn't show up. However the cause of the problem isn't because the order of bookmarks. Even with a correct order it still produces the problem, because the code works from top to bottom. Changing the code to work from bottom to top solves the problem.
